# Alternatives to rest for restoration of spell slots

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spell-slots

Is there a mechanism (established in the rules) for restoring the spell slots of an arcane caster (particularly interested in Wizard) that **does not** involve rest?

The method must be external to the caster (e.g. a potion or an artifact), and cannot require the caster to have chosen specific skills or class abilities.

As a footnote, I am willing to consider divine intervention, but that is akin to me just making up a DM ruling to get the job done.  I need this effect for a story element at the end of a campaign, and would like to keep it legitimate in the context of what is going on.

Comment: @Javelin, a magic item would be a solution (one of which I am not aware), but really the simplest literary way to do this in my campaign would be a Potion of some kind (some kind that doesn't exist)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Possibly

If you are looking for a consumable that restores spells and not an item like the Pearl of Power or Ring of Spell Storage, then you're either looking at:

- A bunch of scrolls, but that is class depenedent, and may limit what your PCs can cast to a set list of scrolls.
- A wand/staff that is destroyed when used, we see a few of these one use items in the index of magical items in the DMG, but none of them quite do what your looking for.  You could however, riff off of the Perl of Power and make it more powerful but single use, or make it break after its charges are expended.
- Making another item specific to your realm like a Potion of Arcane Recovery or some uncommon/rare form of faerie food.

### But...

Now, those last two option I mention might not fit with your requirement:

> As a footnote, I am willing to consider divine intervention, but that is akin to me just making up a DM ruling to get the job done. I need this effect for a story element at the end of a campaign, and would like to keep it legitimate in the context of what is going on.

But creating magical items and consumables is completely within the rules and rights of the DM, as stated in the DMG, where it gives advice about rarity and cost, and building such items (DMG p. 130-143).  If you don't want it to seem like Deus Ex Machina, then make sure the elements already exist in the world.  Perhaps they see enemies using such potions/food before the event against the party.  That way, them receiving them at some point is just par for course, and not some crazy DM hat pull.

I like the idea of a certain faerie food, because you could attach to it a negative side effect for non-fey (maybe elves are immune to effects as well, maybe not) like addiction or a slight buzz that gives them disadvantage on skill checks or the like.

Potion is the smallest departure from the other types of magical items we see in the DMG.

### Otherwise, No.

If you are looking for a ready-made magical item, that is consumable, restores spell slots, and is found in the index of magical items in the DMG I'm afraid you are out of options. The few items listed are examples, and classic items that are cannon to D&D world; but they are a small subset of the items that might exist in a campaign. As such, they don't have any consumable currently listed that does what you want.

Comment: You forgot to put a page number from the DMG

Answer (score 12):

There are several magical items which provide solutions to your problem. I will give a sub-set of them from the 5E SRD, but you may find even more by taking a quick look through the Dungeon Master's Guide

> **A Pearl of Power (pg. 232, SRD):** While    this    pearl   is  on  your    person, you can use an action   to  speak   its command word    and regain  one 
>   expended    spell   slot.   If  the expended    slot    was of  4th 
>   level   or  higher, the new slot    is  3rd level.  Once    you 
>   use the pearl,  it  canʼt   be  used    again   until   the next    dawn.

This next doesn't really restore spell slots but allows you to cast more spells per day.

> **A Ring of Spell Storing (pg. 237, SRD)**: Any   creature    can cast    a   spell   of  1st through 5th level   into the    ring    by  touching    the ring    as  the spell is cast...While   wearing this    ring,   you can cast    any spell   stored  in  it.

And lastly:

> **Rod of Absorption (pg. 239, SRD)**: ...If    you are a   spellcaster holding the rod,    you can convert energy  stored  in  it  into    spell   slots   to  cast    spells  you have    prepared    or  know.   You can create  spell   slots   only    of  a   level   equal   to  or  lower   than    your    own spell   slots,  up  to  a   maximum of  5th level.  You use the stored  levels  in  place   of  your    slots,  but otherwise   cast    the spell   as  normal.

There are lots of options, just take a look at the magic items.

Comment: Thanks, no consumables?  I know, I am really stretching to make something work the story...

Comment: @tillmas I don't mean to sound rude, but If you really need it to be consumable, and it's important for answers to focus on that, please include that detail in your question. And if that's the case, it doesn't have to exist in a book. You can just say that there is a potion that restores spell slots, and use these items and the others in the reference material as a guideline for power.

Comment: If you are just looking to cast more spells, rather than get spell slots back (for some unstated reason), then look into magic wands and staves.

Comment: I honestly was under the impression that pearls of power WERE one-off items - had to go check the pfsrd etc to realize it wan't a 5e-only conceit...

Answer (score 6):

The Pearl of Power (DMG 184) does this:

> You can use an action to speak this pearl's command word and regain one expended spell slot of up to 3rd level.

Answer (score 2):

There is one other way to create spell slots on the fly. But, it will only work if you allow me to bend the rules you set forth in your question somewhat.

### Sorcerers & Flexible Casting

While you are interested in the Wizard class and you are not looking for class-specific skills, since you are looking for a way to restore spell slots all the same, it's worth considering sorcery points for this as well. Flexible Casting allows you to use a bonus action to transform sorcery points into spell points on the fly.

The following are just brainstormed item ideas that you can adapt. As J. A. Streich says in his answer, inventing items is within your rights as a DM. And if you're going to make something up, at the very least, it pays to make it cool and flavorful. Your players will appreciate the new toys.

- **Potion of Sorcery**: Grants *X* sorcery points to an arcane caster when drank for *Y* time. If the caster does not innately have sorcery points, they gain this many and also gain *Flexible Casting* to convert sorcery points to spell slots (and not the other way around) for as long as they have 2 or more sorcery points, or until *Y* time elapses, whichever happens first. If the caster already has these points, then they recover this many points instead.
- **Ring/Staff of Sorcery**: May contain up to *X* sorcery points, which are accessible to an arcane caster when worn. If the caster does not innately have the feature, they gain *Flexible Casting* to convert sorcery points to spell slots (and not the other way around). At dawn of each day, it restores 1d*Y* points. If all the points of this ring are used up, the item becomes a mundane ring.
- **Scroll of Innate Sorcery**: *Xth level spell. Range: ?. Duration: ? (concentration?)*. Choose 1 creature you can see within range. The target of the spell gains the *Flexible Casting* ability if they do not have it yet, plus one Metamagic option from the Sorcerer's list for the duration of the spell. If they do already have it, they gain an extra Metamagic option for the duration of the spell. When this spell's duration expires, they lose all benefits granted by this casting.

There are possibly many other kinds of items you can create around this idea. If you do go this route, I suggest you go with the consumables first just to see how they will play out, before you give them a permanent item.